# how to import a many-to-one dataset into a database (hosted at heroku)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, import

We're using rails3 on heroku and activerecord.

our database has two tables, Keywords and Products

what we would LIKE to import is a single file where each line contains one Product and one or more Keywords (which can be phrases too), something like this:

```
product_number, price_cents, keyword, ..., keyword
item_00001, 100, screwdriver, philips screwdriver, philips
item_00002, 100, screwdriver, flat head screwdriver
item_00205, 500, wrench, crescent wrench, monkey wrench
item_00099, 1500, bulb, light bulb, incandescent light, incandescent
item_01010, 575, widget
```

is there a good gem for importing data, possibly with up to 10,000 lines?

or is this trivially simple using plain old ruby?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is relatively simple using File.open and CSV.parse_line. Here is a start:

```
require 'csv'

File.open(File.dirname(__FILE__) + "path/to/file/file.csv", "r").each_line do |line|
    line_array = CSV.parse_line(line)
    product_number = line_array[0]
    price_cents = line_array[1]
    keywords = line_array[2..-1]
    # create a product here
    keywords.each do |keyword|
         # create a keyword and associate it with product
    end
end
```

Comment: Add creating the AR object and saving it to the DB and you've really got something...

Comment: that's a good approach except at heroku there's no local files, have to upload file. but i'd not seen that [2..-1] trick for a variable number of extra params.

Comment: Heroku does allow local files to be written in /tmp but they do not guarantee they will exist between invocations of the dyno or worker. Static files can be stored in git repository in a /bin directory and pushed to Heroku. You can also open a file with a given URL or you can use aws_s3 to access files stored on Amazon's S3.